# how do I split Chinese string into characters using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, split

I want to use `tf.data.TextLineDataset()` to read Chinese sentences, then use the `map()` function to divide into the single word, but `tf.split` doesn't work for Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

I also hope someone can help us kindly with the issue.
It is my current solution:

1. read Chinese sentence from the file with Utf-8 coding format.
2. tokenize the sentences with some tool like jieba.
3. construct the vocab table.
4. convert source/target sentence according to vocab table.
5. convert to the dataset using from_tensor_slices.
6. get iterator from the dataset.
7. do other things.

if using TextLineDataset to load chinese sentences directlly, the content of dataset is something strange , displayed with byte flow.
maybe we can consider every byte as one character in english kind of language.

can anyone confirm with this or has any other suggestion, plz?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is one common option when handling non-English style language like Chinese, Korean, Japanese, etc.

You can also use the code below.

BTW, as you know, `TextLineDataSet` will read text content as a `byte string`.
So if we want to handle Chinese, we need to first decode it to unicode.
Unfortunately, there is no such option in tensorflow.
We need to choose other method like `py_funct` to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf

def preprocess_func(x):
 ret= "*".join(x.decode('utf-8'))
    return ret

str = tf.py_func(
        preprocess_func,
        [tf.constant(u"我爱，南京")],
        tf.string)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    value = sess.run(str)
    print(value.decode('utf-8'))
```

output: `我*爱*，*南*京`